# don't see Json data result in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, json, forms, jsp

In my .JSP file i have :

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address"><br><br>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="submitform()">
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>
```

and my Javascript function is:

```
function submitform(){

var  userName = $('#name').val();
var  userAdd = $('#address').val();

var myVar = JSON.stringify({name: userName, address:userAdd});

        $ajax({
            url: 'jsonserverlet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'per=' + myVar,
            dataType: 'json',

            success:function(data){

            var json= JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(json + " " + data.name + " " + data.address);
            $("#result").html(data.name + " " + data.address);

            }

        });



};
```

Also I created a new class User.java with some data, then in my Jsoncontent.java , in method POST I set  my variables and created a request for json like this:

```
        String jsonData = request.getParameter("per");
        System.out.println(jsonData);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        User data = gson.fromJson(jsonData, User.class);

        System.out.println("Fetching json object");
        String name = data.getName();
        String address = data.getAddress();

        System.out.println("User Name: "+ name );
        System.out.println("User Address: "+ address );

        User user = new User();

        user.setName(name);
        user.setAddress(address);

        String jsonObj = gson.toJson(user);
        System.out.println(jsonObj);

        out.print(jsonObj);
```

So,all works without errors or warnings but I don't see the result when I click on submit button. I don't know why.

Comment: Did you debug your code or at least use some log statements to see whether the servlet has been called and whether the JavaScript code ran at all?

Comment: yes, i have already tried with try and catch methods to return me something but nothing happens. Yes, the servelet has been called

Comment: Ok. You have posted fragments of code and without the wider context no one can help. Post the full jsp and server side handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You note in the comments to the other answer that *i still have a white browser page yet without name and address* which indicates that the browser is navigating away from the page you are currently viewing and, therefore, you are **not** making an Ajax request - or more likely you are making an Ajax request but are **also** making a standard HTTP Post request due to the fact that you have not disabled the default submit event.

You therefore need to disable the default submit action.

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address"><br><br>
    <input value="Submit" id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<p id="result"></p>
</body>


$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent standard post

        $.ajax({
            url: 'jsonserverlet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',

            success:function(data){
            var json= JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(json + " " + data.name + " " + data.address);
            $("#result").html(data.name + " " + data.address);
            }
        });
})
```

Comment: ********* ok SOLVED! in my form  i miss a id="submit " and the code was correct. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You missed the point: you have $ajax but should be **$.ajax**

Also you can submit form instead of json, like:

```
function submitform(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'jsonserverlet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',

            success:function(data){
            var json= JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(json + " " + data.name + " " + data.address);
            $("#result").html(data.name + " " + data.address);
            }
        });
}
```

And in the servlet get the parameters "name" and "address":

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
    ...
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    ...
}
```

---

**CHANGES IN ANSWER**

Sorry, I only paid attention to the conclusion of the alert message. Alan Hay is right in his remark, you can use it or change the type to a button.
Anyway, here is the working code

*Servlet.java*

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/jsonserverlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String jsonData = request.getParameter("per");
        out.print(jsonData);
    }
}
```

*index.jsp*

```
<html>
<head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
         type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="form">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address"><br><br>
            <input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="submitform()">
        </form>
        <p id="result"></p>
</body>
<script>
function submitform(){
var  userName = $('#name').val();
var  userAdd = $('#address').val();

var myVar = JSON.stringify({name: userName, address:userAdd});
        $.ajax({
            url: 'jsonserverlet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'per=' + myVar,
            dataType: 'json',

            success:function(data){

            var json= JSON.stringify(data);
            alert(json + " " + data.name + " " + data.address);
            $("#result").html(data.name + " " + data.address);
            }
        });
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i fixed the $.ajax .. so It still the same w.hen i run my programm the output of my URL is: http://localhost:8080/Jsoncontent/?name=ergerg&address=egergeg ok, but i still have  a white browser page yet without name and address .

Comment: Check in the servlet whether all data is received correctly and whether it is correctly transmitted in the response

Comment: I tried just sending the same line and everything worked. Like
`response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 String jsonData = request.getParameter("per");
 out.print(jsonData);`

Comment: sorry but , where can i add  this code? always in my post method?

Comment: as I understand you are making an ajax request of type post in servlet, then paste this code into the doPost of the specified servlet

Comment: yes ok but you tried with my code or by your corrections? because i see there that you used a `request.getparameter("per")` that is not present in your correction .